# Can't import FBSDK in Xcode 7 beta, using Swift 2

Tags: facebook, swift2, facebook-login, xcode7, facebook-sdk-4.0

For some reason, Xcode 7 beta with Swift 2, won't let me import the FBSDK framework.

The error reads:

> `No such Module..`

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Describe more about your issue.

Comment: @AshishKakkad  I linked the FBSDK core kit and login kit to my Xcode project, but when I try to import them into my view controller (i.e.: "import FBSDKCoreKit") it gives me an error that reads "No such module 'FBSDKCorekit' "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolved this problem by adding FacebookSDK to the "Framework Search Paths"

Go to Build Settings and search for "framework search"

**OR**

You can try this...

When you are importing the frameworks, Make sure you have selected "Copy if needed ". It's not what Facebook recommends, but it worked!

Comment: Thanks! I just checked "copy if needed" and it worked perfectly.